# Scrolling on landing page (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have landing page with several sections.

Here is code

```
    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" class="about-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>About Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Services Section -->
    <section id="services" class="services-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Services Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact" class="contact-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Contact Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>`
```

I need to make scrolling down like on this website.

[Website](https://www.pqbyronarad.com/)

How I can achieve this?

Thank's for help so much!

Comment: https://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/one-page/

Comment: Please search for any of the available bootstrap single page application themes. Try to implement that in your project and let us know if you see any issues in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want to see, but as you didn't mention any preferences you could just take some prebuild JS or jQuery project like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage) (it's [opensource](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js), [guidance](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/creating-a-full-page-scrolling-website-with-fullpagejs/136)) or [Scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#home) ([opensource](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify) too).

In case this somehow isn't possible for you, check out the tutorial over [here](https://onextrapixel.com/how-to-create-a-beautiful-fullscreen-single-scrolling-page-like-huge-inc/).

I didn't test this, which is why I would've commented that but I can't (sorry for that).

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

[fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) has vertical and horizontal sliding, which is exactly what the site linked has.

Additionally, it also provides a way to have a scrolling bar in one section as in your link too. Check [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

If you also want the mouse drag and drop feature the site provides for horizontal slides, then fullPage.js also provides it with the [Drag And Move extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/drag-and-move.html).